# Stuck booting a Ubuntu 14.04 system (not from a LiveCD but from sdb1) via PXE/NFS

Tags: 14.04, boot, mount, nfs, pxe

I have two disks (sda and sdb). I have a running Ubuntu 14.04 in sda1. I've cloned sda1 in sdb1 with Clonezilla, so in sdb1 I have too another Ubuntu system, which I want to boot only through the LAN. To do so, I'm using sda1's Ubuntu as PXE/NFS server.

To achieve this, I've done these steps:

1.-I've installed in sda1's Ubuntu all PXE stack (dhcpd,tftp, pxelinux.0) and it just works

2.-I've edited sda1's Ubuntu's /etc/fstab file adding this line (where /mnt/pepe already exists):

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/pepe auto defaults 0 0
```

3.-I've edited sda1's Ubuntu's /etc/exports file adding this line:

```
/mnt/pepe  *(rw,no_subtree_check)
```

4.-I've edited sda1's Ubuntu's pxelinux's default file adding these lines:

```
LABEL xxx
    MENU LABEL Ubuntu
    KERNEL vmlinuz
    INITRD initrd
    APPEND netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.1:/mnt/pepe,rw
```

where previously I've added to the initrd file the ability to work with NFS shares (as it is said in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto#Creating_your_NFS_installation). In detail:

1.-I've created a jail in sdb1 system and I've entered into it:

*mount -o bind /dev /mnt/pepe/dev*
*mount -o bind /sys /mnt/pepe/sys*
*mount -o bind /proc /mnt/pepe/proc*
*chroot /mnt/pepe*

2.-Inside the jail I've edited /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf file to have these lines:

```
BOOT=nfs
MODULES=netboot
```

3.-I've created the initrd I'm using with:

*mkinitramfs -o initrd*

4.-I've exited from jail and copyed intrd file to the correct location inside tftp folder.

Nothing more.

What I see when I boot a network client is, lots of error messages like this:

**"Retrying nfs mount...Begin: Running /scripts/nfs-premount ...done.
mount: Stale NFS file handle"**

until I've stuck in a Busybox shell.

I don't know what can I do more.
Help please!
Thanks!!!!